# WPF Ribbon ApplicationMenu Default Menu icon (like wordpad has)

Tags: wpf, ribbon

Hi there with this code I can create nice WPF Menu

```
<Window x:Class="Teletext_Editor.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:ribbon="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Teletext_Editor"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <DockPanel>
            <ribbon:Ribbon DockPanel.Dock="Top">
                <Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>
                    <RibbonApplicationMenu SmallImageSource="Images/ApplicationMenuIcon.png">
                        <RibbonApplicationMenuItem Name="Item1" Header="Pomoc"/>
                    </RibbonApplicationMenu>
                </Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>
            </ribbon:Ribbon>
        </DockPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

But I have been searching for hours for default MenuIcon the one that wordpad has but was unable to find it anywhere, even looked at wordpad resources using Resource Hacker but icon still wasn't there, so if anyone has this icon or can tell me how to enable it that would be great, it seems so simple yet so hard to do

Thanks for Anwsering and Best Regards
[image]

Comment: In Windows 10 it's been replaced by `File` text.

Comment: I know, but I am using windows 7, so would stilll love the icon, just don't know how to enable it

Comment: I don't have win7 but, using IconsExtract (NirLauncher) and renaming all .bin files, there are extra pngs, see if it's there. If not, you can try CFF Explorer to see the import directory  of the exe then check the resources on those imported DLLs.

Comment: hmm, I thought this is a standard icon because this example: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/62436/Windows-Ribbon-for-WinForms-Part-5-Application-Men

also has it, I just cannot find it I thought its some bolean and the icon would be enabled?

Comment: keep in mind that WP is a c++ app, the ribbon you're looking at is totally different from WPF one, as I said, I don't have Win7 so I don't even see it here 

Comment: The icon may be here *The Visual Studio Image Library contains application images that appear in Microsoft Visual Studio, Microsoft Windows, the Office system and other Microsoft software.* https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35825 good luck, there are tons of them

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/internals/image-library-viewer?view=vs-2022